# Conditionally format a cell if it contains formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to conditionally format a cell if the cell contains formula (to alert myself and other users when updating the cell)?

Comment: If you just want to quickly see which cells contain formulas you can type Ctrl-` (that's a back-tick, on the same key as ~ on English keyboards) to display formulas. Press the key again to toggle.

Comment: The best solution has changed in newer versions of Excel - make sure to look at multiple answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a very simple way to do this, tested in Excel 2016.

Highlight your range you wish this to apply to, let's say from `A3:W20`. Go into conditional formatting and select `NEW RULE | USE A FORMULA TO DETERMINE WHICH CELLS TO FORMAT`.

Put in `=isformula(A3)` and pick the format you want to apply.

`A3` is obviously a reference to the first cell in your range but this formatting then applies to all. The result is that within your range, any cell that is a formula is conditionally formatted.

Comment: +1 [Apply to Excel 2013 onwards](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ISFORMULA-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5)

Comment: This works in Google Sheets too. +1.

Comment: Works, but would like to understand why a static A3 value is interpreted as "current cell" instead just A3 when the formula is evaluated.

Answer (score 16):

Building on brettdj's answer, because I found the linked article quite difficult to follow:

1. Create a new Conditional Formatting rule and select *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*
2. Insert the following formula: `=ISFORMULA(INDIRECT("rc",FALSE))`
3. If you want the rule to apply to the whole worksheet, `$1:$1048576` as the range to apply to. Otherwise, you can enter any range.

The formula `INDIRECT("rc",FALSE)` returns the reference of the current cell. If I ever use this in a sheet, I create a Defined Name called something like `ThisCell` and use that in the formula, just in case I ever come back years later and think "what the hell is this for?".

Comment: This is the correct answer for Excel 2013 and later, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ISFORMULA-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5

Comment: Instead of using `INDIRECT("rc",FALSE)`, use relative referencing with the top left cell in your conditional formatting "Applies to" range. For example, if your "Applies to" range is `=$A$3:$F$300`, then use `=ISFORMULA(A3)`. This works because conditional formatting supports relative referencing, see [this](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2012/02/27/conditional-formatting-rules-simplified/)

Answer (score 9):

You can use conditional formatting to do this by using XLM and Range Names

I have a longer article on [Using XLM with Range Names and Conditional Formatting to automatically format spreadsheets according to cell content](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_7629.html)

1. Define a Range Name *IsFormula* =GET.CELL(48,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE))
2. Apply a conditional formatting cells testing for the formula, ie =IsFormula with a colour fill

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tested your answer until now. This trick is simple and beautiful. Accepted! Thanks. (By the way, the link is broken.)

Comment: Tested and it works! I had to find the correct definition for the Italian version of Excel 2007. If you have Italian Excel you must use =INFO.CELLA(48;INDIRETTO("rc";FALSO)) (please note semicolon in place of commas, too)

Comment: The bad part is you need to save it as a macro file (e.g. .xlsm), and when you open the file the coloring does not show until you enable macros.

Comment: You used to be able to use `xlm` without any macro warnings, MSFT changed the security approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can try these:

### VBA

Create a custom function with the following code:

```
Function IsFormula(ByVal Ref As Range) As Variant
    If Ref.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        IsFormula = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Else
        IsFormula = Ref.HasFormula
    End If
End Function
```

Example:

To check if any cells in column A have any formulas:

1. Highlight column A
2. Go to **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule** > **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
3. Use the ff. formula: `=IsFormula(A1)`

### Non-VBA

1. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
2. Click **Special**.
3. Choose **Formulas** and click **OK**. This highlights all cells in the worksheet that contains formulas.
4. Set up the format you'd like to use.
   ***Or***
   Go to **Cell Styles** (under the Home tab) and pick a style that you want to associate with formula-containing cells. To change the look-and-feel, right-click on the style that you selected and click **Modify**. All cells given this style will automatically be updated.

Comment: although i personally don't prefer to use VBA, the VBA solution is better in this case because the cell formatting can be changed dynamically when formula is entered into a cell (or vice versa). thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The newer help sites recommend a User-Defined Function:

```
Function IsFormula(cell) as boolean 
  IsFormula = cell.HasFormula
End Function
```

Then use that function as your condition

And in fact,  Excel 2013 and later has `IsFormula` as a standard function.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use conditional formatting:

1. Select the range of cells you want to apply your conditional formatting to
2. In Home -> Conditional formatting -> New rule: Use a formula to detect which cell to format
3. In Format values when this formula is true put: `=HasNoFormula`
4. Select the format you want

Tested using Excel 2010.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. I don't think you have tested.

Comment: -1, this doesn't do anything. What is =HasNoFormula supposed to do?