# Excel: Conditional format cells with spilled formulas, multiple ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

**UPDATE:** I just found the issue: M5 is a =UNIQUE() formula, and all subsequent columns are referring to M5# and autofills down like arrays.. thus there are only formulas in row 5. I guess Microsoft didn't update the conditional formatting to account for their new array formula UNIQUE().. it worked when I manually wrote a formula in Q9. Visual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFvOb.jpg (*M5,M6,M7,M8 have values, I just edited the image to censor the details before sharing in public*).

..so, could there be another approach to format the cells that are autofilled with values? Even if the result is blank (say, if I wrap it with `=IF(formula=0%,"",formula)`)

**Original post:**

I tried applying the solution found here: [Conditionally format a cell if it contains formula](https://superuser.com/questions/352364/conditionally-format-a-cell-if-it-contains-formula) where you select a range, then write `=isformula(topleftcell)` (N5 in my case). I have multiple ranges for my conditional formatting though, and my range is dynamic (so the number of rows with data change all the time). I want to output blank values when I have a value of 0%, so to be able to hide the data labels when that happens in my charts.

My range is however as I said multiple ranges:

```
=$J$5:$U$60,$X$5:$AI$60,$AL$5:$AW$60,$AZ$6:$BK$60
```

Is it still possible to apply the `=isformula()` formula somehow? When I write `=isformula(J5)` then only row 5 is highlighted.. and I suspect it is because of the multiple ranges that my conditional formatting applies to..
..preferably witout VBA.

..it's baffling that this isn't a standard option yet.

PS! I tried writing the whole range in the isformula formula which just threw an error. I also tried adding multiple ones together, but to get row number two, I have to write J4, then J3 etc, so I run out of numbers fast.. I use O365 if that helps too.

Comment: yeah you can apply a format rule to multiple ranges, just put `=$J$5:$U$60,$X$5:$AI$60,$AL$5:$AW$60,$AZ$6:$BK$60` in the applies to box, and the rule part still applies, write the rule as normal with top most left cell as criteria

Comment: That is exactly what I did.. and it only selected the top row, hence this post.

Comment: ..and it should have been AZ5, but correcting that changed nothing.

Comment: can you post an image of your conditional format, show the rule and the section where it applies too, the error should be easy enough to spot

Comment: As PeterH suggested, could you please provide a screenshot of Conditional Formatting Rules for Manager? Like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfuka.jpg).

Comment: @Emily absolutely: https://imgur.com/i4wqMYA.. Think I just found the issue: M5 is a =UNIQUE() formula, and all subsequent columns are referring to M5# and autofills down like arrays.. thus there are only formulas in row 5. I guess Microsoft didn't update the conditional formatting to account for their new array formula UNIQUE().. it worked when I manually wrote a formula in Q9..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution turned out to be (thanks to [Sergei Baklan @ the Microsoft's Excel forums](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/conditional-format-cells-in-spilled-ranges-as-formulas/m-p/1408008#M63096)):

```
=ISTEXT(N5) + (LEN(N5)>0)
```

As anything I am outputting is counted as text, also when I am outputting ""