# Automatically Change Numbers Color to blue in Excel if the cell contain a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzFyz.png]

The color of the cells changes automatically to blue because it contains a formula

How can I do that?

Comment: Whether you have any plugins installed or used vba.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally format a cell if it contains formula](https://superuser.com/questions/352364/conditionally-format-a-cell-if-it-contains-formula)

Comment: Click on the conditional formatting -> manage rules and see if rules already exist. I would think it would be as @ReddyLutonadio 's link